# What type of adapter/enclosure to get from Amazon U.K. for LITEON CL1-3D256-Q11

Tags: windows, ssd, encryption, pci-express, nvme

[image: Image. A close up photo of a small solid state drive marked P C I E, Gen 3, ex 4, Solid State Drive, model C L 1, dash 3 D 2 5 6, dash Q 11, N V M E, light on, 256 Gigabytes]

Friend of mine’s Dell Windows inspiron 2-in-1 laptop/tablet won’t boot, has unbacked up last three years of uni work on it, including his final dissertation of this year. It goes into a windows recovery environment which loops around about bitlocker recovery key while providing a key ID, we went into windows recovery environment command prompt and used manage-bde -protectors -get c: which displays the same ID under numerical passwords, but not the actual key of that ID. There is another section above that about something about TPM.

We have successfully managed to boot into a live Manjaro environment by disabling secure boot. But the internal drive was not even detected this time by Manjaro, much less any kind of encrypted volume that might be on it.

Actually even this bitlocker business is just weird, because he says he never had it encrypted at all in the first place.

So we’ve managed to take the internal SSD drive out of the device, and I guess the first next step at this stage is just to procure a suitable enclosure for the thing so that we can put it into another working Windows and maybe then a Linux machine to just see if the thing can even just be detected.

Any levels of advice or insight including at this stage simply what type of enclosure to buy would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Without the BitLocker key the data cannot be recovered. BitLocker isn’t enabled without user intervention. Enclosures for that type of SSD don’t exist since it doesn’t appear to be NVMe. By the way you mistakenly tagged this has M.2 that isn’t a M.2 drive.

Comment: I cropped & rotated to make it legible.

Comment: @Ramhound That seems to be a regular M.2 NVMe drive in 2230 format (width 22mm height 30mm) that is produced by LiteOn and then labels as Dell product. The notch is in the M position (4 PCIe lanes), visible in the original image now only shown in the question edit history.

Comment: @Robert okay, but what type of enclosure would fit it?